# Swift SKPhysicsBody empty subclass doesn't inherit parent inits

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

While trying to inherit from SkPhysicsBody I found something rather strange : 
None of the convenience init are inherited!

Here is the code you can test in a playground :

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

public class SKPhysicsBodySubClass:SKPhysicsBody
{

}

let pb = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 10)
let pbsc = SKPhysicsBodySubClass(circleOfRadius: 10)
```

The last instruction produce an error suggesting that the parent init doesn't exist : "Incorrect argument label in call (have 'circleOfRadius:', expected 'coder:')"

I'm also aware of the rule of inheritance :

> Rule 1 : 
>   If your subclass doesn’t define any designated initializers, it automatically inherits all of its superclass designated initializers.
>
> Rule 2 : 
>   If your subclass provides an implementation of all of its superclass designated initializers—either by inheriting them as per rule 1, or by providing a custom implementation as part of its definition—then it automatically inherits all of the superclass convenience initializers.

Any idea what's going on here? what did I miss?

Comment: 1) You shouldn't subclass SKPhysicsBody because it is only a wrapper that creates a PKPhysicsBody  2) circleOfRadius is most likely a convenience initializer, so you need to apply rule 2

Comment: Thank you for your answer, If I may, if i shouldn't subclass SKPhysicsBody it should be final.
Also, my subclass doesn't have anything in it, which mean that rule 1 is applied (If your subclass doesn’t define any designated initializers...) and in any case my subclass should inherit the convenience init.
And to finish, what is PKPhysicsBody? I can't find anything on it.
Thank's again.

Comment: Only Rule 1 applies to you, but like I said, I am pretty sure that circleOfRadius is a convenience init, so you need Rule 2. I believe the provision of "either by inheriting them as per rule 1" is inaccurate because of how SKPhysicsBody works (It isn't inheriting all of it's supers).  PKPhysicsBody is an internal object that you do know have access to.  PK stands for PhysicsKit, which is Apple's private API based on Box2D

Comment: Thank's for the tip on PhysicsKit! 
I agree both rule 1 and 2 apply. And therefore the convenience init should be inherited. Even if SKPhysicsBody is just a wrapper, it still has init and convenience init that should be inherited.