# reproducible results for SKPhysicsBody collisions?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I'm using Swift 5 with the iPhone 12 simulator.  When I create a number of simple shapes and let gravity pull them down the result differs from run to run.

My eventual goal is to create a two player game where I can rely on the physics simulation to have the exact same results on two different devices.  I was hoping I could find a way to seed the RNG somewhere, or at least get deterministic results.

Any pointers would be gratefully received.

Snippets of the test code:

**(in SKScene)**

```
        // Setup the boundaries -- whole screen for now
        let boundary = SKNode()
        boundary.position = .zero
        boundary.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: self.size))
        addChild(boundary)
        
        for i in 1...20 {
            let groundTile = GroundTileClass(diameter: 2, location: CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: Double(i)*20.0))
            self.addChild(groundTile)
        }
        let biggerTile = GroundTileClass(diameter: 20, location: CGPoint(x: 200, y: 1000))
        self.addChild(biggerTile)
        let biggerTile2 = GroundTileClass(diameter: 20, location: CGPoint(x: 400, y: 1000))
        self.addChild(biggerTile2)
```

**(GroundTileClass)**

```
class GroundTileClass : SKShapeNode {
    init(diameter : UInt32, location : CGPoint) {
        
        super.init()
        
        // Create a hexagon ground tile
    
        self.path = createHexagonPath(diameter: diameter, location: location)
        self.strokeColor = SKColor.green
        self.fillColor = SKColor.systemPink
        self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(polygonFrom: self.path!)
        self.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
        self.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ObjectCategoryEnum.groundCategory.rawValue
        self.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = ObjectCategoryEnum.groundCategory.rawValue
    }
}
```

[image: Sample 1]

[image: Sample 2]

Comment: How are the results different and what are you expecting?

Comment: The two pictures at the bottom of the post show two different final states from two different runs of the same program.  I am looking for a way to make sure that the final state is always identical when the exact same code runs.

Comment: this is not possible as far as i know. the obvious solution would be to subclass `SKPhysicsBody` and then override functions like `applyForce` and `applyAngularImpulse` etc to quantize/standardize the values. however [you can't subclass SKPhysicsBody](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58844439/swift-skphysicsbody-empty-subclass-doesnt-inherit-parent-inits). the other idea i had was to use `SKPhysicsContactDelegate` and regularize values at that step. but i just tested it and it doesn't produce reliable results

Comment: Fault is correct. I think there is a tiny bit of randomness included in the physics based on my own past experiences.

Comment: Even if there were no randomness in the physics computations themselves, they're tied to the frame rate in SpriteKit.  So you have to consider devices with different screen refresh rates, thermal throttling, low-battery power-save modes, other concurrent activities on the device, etc.  You're going to have to think about such issues and, most likely, carefully roll your own physics.